# Why unity will not find my folder?

Tags: unity, search

I have a folder in my `/home/me/` directory called "podcast", and when I click on Unity's left menu "Files & Folders" and type "podcast" in the search, it shows nothing. Also, if I select to search "Folders" instead of "All Files" it still finds nothing.

Why it doesn't work? Is it only with me?

Comment: @Jorge Castro mine is about a folder, not files (and I have used the folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search for existing files, then you should do that in Nautilus. If you want quick access to files you've used, then the Files and Folders lens is great tool. Perhaps in the future, there will be another lens for it, but at least for now, the lens searches the Zeitgeist log for file events. I think that's a good thing, because it means the system learns from my actions instead of just providing a "dumb" search.

But I do think, from a usability point of view, that both types of searches should be available from the same place. It's a work in progress :)

Comment: Here is tha associated bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-place-files/+bug/646724

Comment: It seems crazy that the Files and Folders lens doesn't use the Locate database but that seems to be the case from that bug thread.

Comment: @amanda There's a dconf setting com.canonical.Unity.FilesLens: use-locate. I think it's accessible through System Settings in 12.04, but I can't find it there in 13.10. You might want to edit that into the answer.